# Can I travel to UK if my Schengen visa expired before six months?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am staying in Germany in a student visa. My resident permit will finish on 15th November, 2018. Can I apply for a visiting visa for UK from July 2018?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply for a UK visit visa at any time. Edit: But see Traveller's comment below.

It will likely help your application that you are a student in Germany, assuming you still have university work to complete after your visit.

Comment: @Jomon Mularikkal You can apply for a UK Standard Visitor visa up to 3 months before your intended travel date. Typically you need to allow at least 15 working days for the decision.